# File transfer progression with Nanohttpd

Tags: java, android, httpserver, nanohttpd

I want to make a very simple server that could be used both on Java Desktop and Android, hence I will probably go with the small library [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd). If anyone has a better alternative, feel free to recommend it.

As such, the server is mostly for file **reception** from many custom WiFi only devices and for pushing some settings to them. However, since the files are potentially quite big (200Mb+) and the transfer rate slow I need to be able to access from the server (Android/PC) the progression of this transfer.

Is there a way with NanoHttpd to get this progress? As of now, I seem to be understanding that the request is received entirely before the 'serve()' method is called, and the download is finished.

Comment: it is not clear on which side you want to know the progress.

Comment: On the server side, I want to know the progress of the POST request but I seem to receive it when it is already done.

Comment: which one is *other side*? Server side, or client side?

Comment: Client sends a POST request with a file to the server, I want to know **from the server** (eg. in the serve() method of nanohttpd) the progression of the file transfer. I do not care for the progress on the client side as it is mostly going to be a quasi headless automated device (no screen).

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but I guess it will help anybody reaching here.

If you are talking about the progress of a file that `nanohttpd` is serving, you can do that very easily. Copy paste this class into your code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProgressInputStream extends InputStream {

    private InputStream in;
    private int length, sumRead;
    private java.util.List<Listener> listeners;
    private double percent;

    public ProgressInputStream(InputStream inputStream, int length) {
        this.in = inputStream;
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
        sumRead = 0;
        this.length = length;
    }


    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        int readCount = in.read(b);
        evaluatePercent(readCount);
        return readCount;
    }


    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int readCount = in.read(b, off, len);
        evaluatePercent(readCount);
        return readCount;
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long skip = in.skip(n);
        evaluatePercent(skip);
        return skip;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int read = in.read();
        if (read != -1) {
            evaluatePercent(1);
        }
        return read;
    }

    public ProgressInputStream addListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listeners.add(listener);
        return this;
    }

    private void evaluatePercent(long readCount) {
        if (readCount != -1) {
            sumRead += readCount;
            percent = sumRead * 1.0 / length;
        }
        notifyListener();
    }

    private void notifyListener() {
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.process(percent);
        }
    }
}
```

An interface for progress

```
public interface ProgressListener {
    void process(double percent);
}
```

now you can get about progress of any file being served by `nanohttpd` by writing this code in `serve` method

```
@Override
public NanoHTTPD.Response server(NanoHTTPD.IHTTPSession session) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if(session.getUri().equals("/file_to_be_served")) {
        File file = new File("file_to_be_served");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ProgressInputStream pis = new ProgressInputStream(fis, (int) file.length());
        pis.addListener(mProgressListener);
        return newChunkedResponse(NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.OK, "mime_type_of_the_file", pis);
    }
}
```

`file_to_be_served` will be the path of the file and `mime_type_of_the_file` should be the `mimetype`.

Now you can modify this boilerplate code for as per your need. Hope it will help everybody.

Comment: Good answer, but I would recommend to explain your solution to the problem instead of offering a complete code. Try to avoid phrases like "Copy paste this class into your code" as SO should be a place to help others develop not just a place to come and copy code.

Comment: Is `now you can get about progress of …` missing an object?